# How to plot bokeh image with non-uniform pixel width

Tags: python, bokeh

I've been working on a web-app to produce images using Bokeh in Python and have been having trouble making images with non-uniform pixel width.  The type of behavior that I'd like to have is similar to the `NonUniformImage` function from the `matplotlib.image` module, but I want it to be interactive in the browser, which is why I use Bokeh.

The data that I want to plot has a fixed pixel width in the vertical direction, but each column can have a different pixel width.  Now, the only way that I could figure out how to make a variable width column in an image plot was to slice each column into its own image and plot them all as separate images with the appropriate widths.  While this does plot things with the widths I want, it has a rendering issue in between each of the pixels where white lines show up depending on the level of zoom.  These white lines will translate to the saved images as well.  I've written up some sample code below:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models import Range1d
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file

# Sample Data
img = np.array([[(x/10.*255,y/10.*255,100,255) for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)])

# Convert to RGBA array that can be plotted
d = np.empty((10, 10), dtype=np.uint32)
view = d.view(dtype=np.uint8).reshape((10, 10, 4))
view[:,:,:] = img

# Set output file
output_file("image.html", title="image.py example")

# Setup the figure
rng = Range1d(0,10,bounds='auto')
p = figure(x_range=rng, y_range=rng, plot_width=500, plot_height=500,active_scroll='wheel_zoom')

# Slice the images
imgs = [d[:,n:n+1] for n in range(10)]
dhs = [10 for n in range(10)]
ys = [0 for n in range(10)]
dws = [0.5 if n%2 == 0 else 1.5 for n in range(10)]
xs = [sum(dws[:n]) for n in range(10)]

# Plot the image
p.image_rgba(image=imgs, x=xs, y=ys, dw=dws, dh=dhs)
show(p)
```

Now, my real data is much denser than this sample data, so the rendering is dominated by the white vertical lines.  If you zoom in far enough, you can see that the pixels are right next to each other.

So, my question is the following:  Is there a better way to plot a non-uniform image in Bokeh?  Something that can take in x,y position information for each pixel would be preferable.  Or, is there a way I can get the rendering to work better using this method to avoid the white stripes?

EDIT: It seems that if I give the pixels some overlap then it gets rid of the striping. But there is a limit to that, the overlap needs to be sufficiently large, which seems like a pretty sketchy way of doing things.  I'll think about this some more, as it could be a work-around, but I'd like to have a more reasonable solution.

Comment: That could be a great feature for bokeh. It should be requested at https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh .

Comment: Another workaround could be doing yourself the interpolation e.g. using  `scipy.interpolate.interp2d` where your new set of x and y coordinates are uniformly sampled.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion, because on the dense data sets that I have, slicing the image makes the rendering take much longer.  I'll give that a shot.  Also, I can make a new request at the link that you gave and see if it can be implemented in one of the newer versions.  Thanks for the tip.